# How to show 5 records in 5 different <DIV > tags using jquery PHP Mysql with Next /prev button

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pagination

I have html page whicha has 5 Div tags in disable mode. what I want is

Imagine I have 200 records in mysql database table

1. Using Jquery I want to call PHP Mysql data (only 5 records at a time)
2. When user clicks on Next button PHP page will get called Limit 6, 10 and so on
3. if user  clicks on Prev button then previous 5 records

following example is good enough bit it has pagination with numbers i want Next/Prev buttons.

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/09/pagination-with-jquery-mysql-and-php.html

Comment: Show us what code you have so far, and what part specifically you are having problems with.

Comment: same like following example only I need Next/Prev functionality I dont want 1 2 3 4 5 pagination numbers.

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/09/pagination-with-jquery-mysql-and-php.html

Answer (score 0):

For starters in **pagination.php**

Change this:

```
//Pagination Numbers
for($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++)
{
echo '<li id="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</li>';
}
```

To this:

```
// Show 'next' link
echo '<li id="'.2.'">Next page</li>';
```

To create you first 'next'-link.

Then add some jQuery code to

- Add a prev button when you click to
  the next page(only if currentpage = 1) and remove it again on page 1
- Include your result's count as a js-var, so  you will know when the last page is reached to remove the next  button.
- On each load, change page number's  +/- 1

Your php stays the same since you always send a page id to use in your query.

Have you tried writing this yourself?
If so, where did you encounter problems?